# Matplotlib - Default optional arguments for plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I came across python behavior that I would like to understand. Take a look at the following lines.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
plt.plot(x, x, 'k', color=None)
plt.plot(x, x**2, 'k', color=None)
```

According to the matplotlib documentation the plot-kwargs are defined in the [Line2D class](https://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html). There, we find that color takes 'None' as default argument. Hence the plot ought to be black and white. However, the output is colorful.

[image]

If I remove the optional color argument, I get black lines. So my question is, why is the above plot colored, even though I passed None as a color-option?

Edit: I understand that removing `color=None` leads to `'k'` being used as the color option. However, I would like to understand how matplotlib internally can distuingish between

```
plt.plot(x, x, 'k', color=None)
```

and

```
plt.plot(x, x, 'k')
```

if the color argument is `None` by default. (Which it is according to the documentation.)

Comment: Having `None` as the default argument indicates to matplotlib that a value for the `color` argument was not specified, so default values are used. It is not for disabling colour.

Comment: I still don't understand how that is possible in python. Say, I define a function `def foo(a=None)`. I don't see how it could be possible to find out weather I call it as `foo()` or `foo(a=None)`. But apparently, matplotlib can distinguish between these two calls as it shifts from colorful to black and white. Do you know why?

Comment: It depends how the function is written. If the function is `def foo(a=None)` then yes, the two calls are equivalent. If instead it is defined as `def foo(**kwargs)`, `kwargs` will be an empty dictionary for `foo()`, and `{'a': None}` for `foo(a=None)`. The behaviour is then up to how the function handles `kwargs`

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `plt.plot(x, x, 'k', color=None)`, you have two color definitions. The first is the positional argument `'k'` (black), the second is the keyword argument `color=None`.

If you leave out the `color=None`, the positional argument `'k'` will be used and the lines will be black. No supprise here.

If you specify `color=None`, it will overwrite the `'k'` argument. Thus `color=None` will determine the color and that means a color is chosen according to the [current color cycle](https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#colors-color-cycles-and-color-maps).

To answer the question on how it is possible to distinguish the cases:

First let me note that the way matplotlib manages arguments and keyword arguments to finally decide upon the properties of the lines is rather complex. To see what actually happens, you may start at [the `plot` function](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L1396) and follow the arguments through the various functions and classes. 
To explain everything here would be too much, so let's look at an example of how it *could*  be done in a simplified way.

The plot method does not look like `def plot(x,y,something, color=None)`, but simply `def plot(*args,**kwargs)`.

Therefore `color` is not an argument, but a keyword argument. A way the two color arguments could be disinguished would e.g. look like

```
def plot(*args,**kwargs):
    x = args[0]
    y = args[1]
    if len(args) > 2:
        color = args[2]
    else:
        color = None
    color = kwargs.get("color", color)
    print color

plot([1,2],[3,4], "k", color=None) # prints None
plot([1,2],[3,4], "k")             # prints k
plot([1,2],[3,4], color=None)      # prints None
plot([1,2],[3,4])                  # prints None
```

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed true. However, I still don't understand how that is possible in python, see the comment to my question.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The Parameter `'k'` is the color abbreviation for the color black. 
But when you set `color=None` it overrides black with `None` which means matplotlib will use default colors.

matplotlib will then automatically cycle through colors. By default, it cycles through blue, green, red, cyan, magenta, yellow, black.

Edit: In matplotlib 2.0 default color cycle has been changed: [source](https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html)

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed true. However, I still don't understand how that is possible in python, see the comment to my question.